# Partial Derivative for Stochastic Integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Good day, I am trying to apply Ito's lemma to find an integral but I am struggling with my choice of functions.

$\int^ T _0 tdW(t) = T W(T)- \int^T_ 0W(t)dt$

Our version of Itos lemma states the following:

For twice continuously differentiable functions $f$ and Ito processes
$$dS_t = \mu_tdt + \sigma_tdW_t$$
we have that
$$df(S)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}(\mu_t dt + \sigma_t dW) + \dfrac{1}{2}\sigma_t^2\frac{\partial^2f }{\partial S^2}dt$$.

This can be written as:

$$f(S(T))-f(S(0))=\int_0^T \mu\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}+\dfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2f }{\partial S^2}dt +\int_0^T\sigma\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}dW. $$

When I try to apply the lemma, I only get that $S(t)=W(t)$ and we have to put $f=tS$. But I feel that I am missing something when I differentiate.

Comment: Your formula for $dS$ is missing coefficients. The complete Ito formula should be for $f(t,S)$ and state that $$df=\frac{∂f}{∂t}dt+\frac{∂f}{∂S}dS+\frac12\frac{∂^2f}{∂S^2}d\langle S\rangle.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is "another" Ito formula concerning functions $f(t, S)$.
It states that for every Ito process $S = (S_t)_{t \geq 0}$ we have that
$$
d\bigl(f(t, S_t) \bigr) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t, S_t) dt + \frac{\partial}{\partial S} f(t, S_t) dW_t + \frac12 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial S^2} f(t, S_t) \sigma^2 dt.
$$

Now you can apply this version of the Ito formula for $S_T = W_T$ and $f(t, s) = t \cdot s$.
This results in:

$$
d\bigl(t \cdot W_t\bigr) = W_t dt + t dW_t + 0,
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$
T \cdot W_T  = \int_{0}^T W_s ds + \int_{0}^T s dW_s
$$